# RFECV y GridSearchCV en python

Tags: python

Estoy entrenando un modelo y para ello necesito hacer una sección de atributos (con RFECV) y optimizar los parámetros del modelo (GridSearchCV).

**Código**

```
model = LogisticRegression() #algoritmo

my_scorer = make_scorer(score, greater_is_better=True) #Se crea el'score' de la función propia creada
generador_train = GroupKFold(n_splits=10).split(X_train, y_train, order_train) #Generador para creación de los 10 splits siguiendo un orden dado
C= {'C': 10. ** np.arange(-3, 4)} #valores de C
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler() #Estandarizado 
selector =RFECV(cv=generador_train, estimator=model,scoring=my_scorer) #Seleccion de atributos

pipe=Pipeline([('scaler', scaler),('select', selector),('model', model)]) # Se crea la pipeline


grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid=C,cv=generador_train,scoring=my_scorer,refit=True) #Se declara el gridSearch con CV

grid.fit(X_train, y_train) # Se ejecuta la pipeline         
best_pipe=grid.best_estimator_
```

Al ejecutar el código anterior me aparece el error:

```
- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-34-9d038a773283> in <module>()
>      17 
>      18     grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid=C,cv=generador_train,scoring=my_scorer,refit=True) #Se
> declara el gridSearch con CV
> ---> 19     grid.fit(X_train,y_train)
>      20     best_pipe=grid.best_estimator_
> 
> AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py
> in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
>     622                                      n_candidates * n_splits))
>     623 
> --> 624         base_estimator = clone(self.estimator)
>     625         pre_dispatch = self.pre_dispatch
>     626 
> 
> AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py
> in clone(estimator, safe)
>      59     new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
>      60     for name, param in six.iteritems(new_object_params):
> ---> 61         new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)
>      62     new_object = klass(**new_object_params)
>      63     params_set = new_object.get_params(deep=False)
> 
> AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py
> in clone(estimator, safe)
>      47     # XXX: not handling dictionaries
>      48     if estimator_type in (list, tuple, set, frozenset):
> ---> 49         return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
>      50     elif not hasattr(estimator, 'get_params'):
>      51         if not safe:
> 
> AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py
> in <listcomp>(.0)
>      47     # XXX: not handling dictionaries
>      48     if estimator_type in (list, tuple, set, frozenset):
> ---> 49         return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
>      50     elif not hasattr(estimator, 'get_params'):
>      51         if not safe:
> 
> AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py
> in clone(estimator, safe)
>      47     # XXX: not handling dictionaries
>      48     if estimator_type in (list, tuple, set, frozenset):
> ---> 49         return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
>      50     elif not hasattr(estimator, 'get_params'):
>      51         if not safe:
> 
> AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py
> in <listcomp>(.0)
>      47     # XXX: not handling dictionaries
>      48     if estimator_type in (list, tuple, set, frozenset):
> ---> 49         return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
>      50     elif not hasattr(estimator, 'get_params'):
>      51         if not safe:
> 
> AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py
> in clone(estimator, safe)
>      59     new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
>      60     for name, param in six.iteritems(new_object_params):
> ---> 61         new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)
>      62     new_object = klass(**new_object_params)
>      63     params_set = new_object.get_params(deep=False)
> 
> AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py
> in clone(estimator, safe)
>      50     elif not hasattr(estimator, 'get_params'):
>      51         if not safe:
> ---> 52             return copy.deepcopy(estimator)
>      53         else:
>      54             raise TypeError("Cannot clone object '%s' (type %s): "
> 
> AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\copy.py in
> deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
>     167                     reductor = getattr(x, "__reduce_ex__", None)
>     168                     if reductor:
> --> 169                         rv = reductor(4)
>     170                     else:
>     171                         reductor = getattr(x, "__reduce__", None)
> 
> TypeError: can't pickle generator objects
```

¿Cómo se puede solucionar? ¿A qué puede ser debido?

**Actualización:**

He puesto:

```
list(generador_train = GroupKFold(n_splits=10).split(X_train, y_train, order_train))
```

pero he obtenido este error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-150-d0ca294b7811> in <module>()
 25 
 26 grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid=C, cv=generador_train,scoring=my_scorer,refit=True) #Se declara el gridSearch con  CV
---> 27 grid.fit(X_train, y_train) # Se ejecuta la pipeline
 28 #grid.fit(digits.data, digits.target)
 29 #res=pipe.named_steps['select'].grid_scores_ #Resultados gridSearch

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
637                                   error_score=self.error_score)
638           for parameters, (train, test) in product(candidate_params,
--> 639                                                    cv.split(X, y, groups)))
640 
641         # if one choose to see train score, "out" will contain train score info

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in     __call__(self, iterable)
777             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
778             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 779             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
780                 self._iterating = True
781             else:

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in  dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
623                 return False
624             else:
--> 625                 self._dispatch(tasks)
626                 return True
627 

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
586         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
587         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
--> 588         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
589         self._jobs.append(job)
590 

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
109     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
110         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 111         result = ImmediateResult(func)
112         if callback:
113             callback(result)

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
330         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
331         # arguments in memory
--> 332         self.results = batch()
333 
334     def get(self):

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
129 
130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
132 
133     def __len__(self):

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
129 
130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
132 
133     def __len__(self):

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, error_score)
456             estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
457         else:
--> 458             estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
459 
460     except Exception as e:

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
246             This estimator
247         """
--> 248         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
249         if self._final_estimator is not None:
250             self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
211                 Xt, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
212                     cloned_transformer, None, Xt, y,
--> 213                     **fit_params_steps[name])
214                 # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
215                 # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
360 
361     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 362         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
363 
364     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, weight, X, y, **fit_params)
579                        **fit_params):
580     if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 581         res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
582     else:
583         res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
518         else:
519             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
--> 520             return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
521 
522 

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\rfe.py in fit(self, X, y)
434         scores = parallel(
435             func(rfe, self.estimator, X, y, train, test, scorer)
--> 436             for train, test in cv.split(X, y))
437 
438         scores = np.sum(scores, axis=0)

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\rfe.py in <genexpr>(.0)
434         scores = parallel(
435             func(rfe, self.estimator, X, y, train, test, scorer)
--> 436             for train, test in cv.split(X, y))
437 
438         scores = np.sum(scores, axis=0)

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\rfe.py in _rfe_single_fit(rfe, estimator, X, y, train, test, scorer)
 26     Return the score for a fit across one fold.
 27     """
 ---> 28     X_train, y_train = _safe_split(estimator, X, y, train)
 29     X_test, y_test = _safe_split(estimator, X, y, test, train)
 30     return rfe._fit(

 ~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py in _safe_split(estimator, X, y, indices, train_indices)
198             X_subset = X[np.ix_(indices, train_indices)]
199     else:
--> 200         X_subset = safe_indexing(X, indices)
201 
202     if y is not None:

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in safe_indexing(X, indices)
158                                    indices.dtype.kind == 'i'):
159             # This is often substantially faster than X[indices]
--> 160             return X.take(indices, axis=0)
161         else:
162             return X[indices]

IndexError: index 182 is out of bounds for size 182
```

Comment: El error pareciera ser simplemente que hay generador que no puedes serializarlo con pickle, por el código que has compartido no me doy cuenta dónde podría ser. ¿Podrías copiar el código de error completo?

Comment: Gracias por contestar @PatricioMoracho .Ya he editado la pregunta para añadir el error completo.